# change a variable in javascript file in npm build script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I want to change a path in a javascript file so my image shows up in my development deployment as well as in my production deployment and the paths are different for each deploy. For example:

```js
var imgPath = "/CMSTemplates/ToolingU8/img/";
<img src={imgPath + "Tooling-U-logo.png"} alt="logo" style={{height: "51px", width: "248px", margin: "1em" }}/>
```

In the deploy script for dev, I want to change `imgPath` to be `includes/img/`

So when I run `npm run build:dev` it would have one path and `npm run build:prod` another.

Is this possible?